# Why does my random number generator method brings back the same numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

I want this program to bring back a new set of numbers every time the 'Generate Number' button is clicked, that is 6 integer numbers between 0 and 10.

[image: GUI for the program]

However, it brings back the same set of numbers even after clicking the button again and again.

This is the Model class code that generates the number:

```
public class Number {
    int[] num = new int[6];
    Random ran = new Random(10);

    public int[] generate(){

        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        {
            num[i] = ran.nextInt(10);
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

and this is how this code gets called from the `ActionListener` method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Number numb = new Number();
    lot_num.setText(Arrays.toString(numb.generate()));

}
```

I also can't tell how to manage the format of the result so that it is spaced through the text field without the commas and the brackets.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  I'm not sure that they *knew* that they were setting the seed, necessarily.

Comment: Sort of relevent about [randomness](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)

Comment: replace `Random ran = new Random(10);` with `static final Random ran = new Random();`

Comment: @Lashane:  It doesn't need to be static.

Comment: @Makoto What difference does that make? The answers in the linked post explain all of this.

Comment: @Makoto in this case its needs to be static, otherway you will create new Random every time you click on button, so in case of very fast click - you still have chance to get the same seed

Comment: @Lashane:  That's not true; it's a field in their `Number` class.  Perhaps the instance of `Number` where the event is called needs to be pulled up to a field, but that doesn't mean it needs to be static.

Comment: @Makoto `That's not true;` - nope, its true. `Perhaps the instance of Number where the event is called needs to be pulled up` - its another solution to the problem, which also will work

Answer (score 7):

[You've seeded your PRNG.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long))  You're not going to get any different values with that.

Simply remove the seed on initialization.

```
Random ran = new Random();
```